# How do I logout from SVN session after completing my execution in Unix

Tags: unix, svn

I will describe whatever I have tried so far.

Suppose I want to create a directory in my repository I have used the following command.

```
svn mkdir https://"Server path/NEW_DIRECTORY -m "Create a directory"
```

So when I run this command, it prompts for password and when i type in the password, It asks whether the password should be stored in encrypted form or not. If I say store in an unencrypted format, then for all my future svn commands I don't have to give in my password. Now I want to logout from svn. How do i do this?

Answer (score 12):

A logout command does not exist in SVN.

If you never want to 'login', use following option on every svn command:

```
--no-auth-cache
```

Otherwise, you might want to remove the credentials already stored in SVN cache:

On Unix, it's: `rm $HOME/.subversion/auth.`

On Windows, it's in: `%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth` or `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Subversion\auth\`

Comment: Hi Ivan, Thanks for the answer. I have a doubt. I'm writing a for loop, and inside the loop I'm calling the svn command. So is it possible that only for the first time, there is a prompt for a password and going on it can automatically connect?

Comment: Why don't you use --username XXXX --password YYYY in your loop?

Answer (score 4):

SVN clients and web browsers do not keep active connection to the server so there is no need to log them off. Every client request is getting authenticated. However, if you use Basic authentication (password-based) SVN may cache your credentials automatically.

You can run [**`svn auth`**](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9.html#svn-auth) to view the contents of the credential cache.

Here are the areas where SVN may store client credentials:

- Windows: `%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\`
- MacOS: OS Keychain
- Linux/ Unix-like: `~/.subversion/auth/`, various keychains

Read [SVNBook | Client Credentials](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.serverconfig.netmodel.creds).